# Graph API - course with gaps

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am currently creating course object with success. My points, however, are not continous (and I know where are the gaps). When uploading the data to Facebook, all points are automatically linked, which gives bad graph of the track. Is it possible to create a course in open graph api with specified gaps between certain points?

```
    let track = MyTrack()
    var properties = [String : Any]()

    properties["og:type"] = "fitness.course"
    properties["og:title"] = "MyTitle"
    properties["og:description"] = "MyDesc"

    properties["fitness:distance:value"] = track.totalDistance.kmRounded()
    properties["fitness:distance:units"] = "km"
    properties["fitness:duration:value"] = track.totalTime
    properties["fitness:duration:units"] = "s"
    properties["fitness:speed:value"] = track.averageSpeed()
    properties["fitness:speed:units"] = "m/s"

    //locationSamples is array of subArrays of points (points from subArrays are not to be linked after upload
    track.locationSamples.flatMap({ $0 }).enumerated().forEach({

                properties["fitness:metrics[\($0)]:location:latitude"] = $1.coordinate.latitude
                properties["fitness:metrics[\($0)]:location:longitude"] = $1.coordinate.longitude
            })

    let object = FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject(properties: properties)
    let action = FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction()

    action.actionType = "fitness.bikes"
    action.setObject(object, forKey: "fitness:course")

    let content = FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent()

    content.action = action
    content.previewPropertyName = "fitness:course"
```